# Finding the biggest subset of vectors, that has the same dot product with some other vector

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, inner-products

In my research, I stumbled upon a problem, that I thought should have an easy solution, but I really cannot figure it out by myself. The setup is the following. Let $A \in \mathbb{N}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}^m$. This way we get a system of linear equations $Ax=b$. For my purposes $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ but we will assume that $A$ does not contain any zero-columns and there does actually exist a solution $x \in \mathbb{N}^n$ to the system of equations. Now let $a_j$ be the $j$-th column of $A$. The goal is to find a $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

- $\mu \cdot a_j > 0$ for all $j \in [n]$
- As many columns of $A$ as possible have the same dot product with $\mu$

The bigger the subset of columns with the same dot-product the better my algorithm can get to solve ILPs. It would suffice to find a polynomal time algorithm to determine the biggest subset. So far, I didn't get much further than just trying all possible subsets if there exists such a $\mu$, which is obviously in exponential time.

---

**A bit of context if you are interested**
It essentially boils down to minimizing a certain function:
$$k(\mu) = \max_{j \in [m]}\left\{\frac{\mu\cdot b}{\mu\cdot a_j}\right\} =: \max_{j\in[n]}\{k_j(\mu)\}$$
$k$ is only defined on $U = \{\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \forall a_j\colon \mu \cdot a_j > 0\}$. So $k$ is actually continous.
I found out that $k_j(\mu)$ is either strictly monotone or constant. So $k$ is the upper envelope of monotone functions. Also the boundary of the domain cannot contain the minimum as there $k$ explodes to infinity. So the only interesting regions, where the minimum can be located, are the boundaries between regions where different $k_j$ produce the value of $k$ (meaning its value is larger than all others). In other words, the only interesting regions are those where at lest 2 $k_j$'s have the same value (so $a_{j_1} \cdot \mu = a_{j_2} \cdot \mu$).
But I also found out that $k$ restricted to these boundaries is also either strictly monotone or constant. This fact doesn't change, no matter how many dot products should match.
Thus I concluded, that the only interesting regions are those, where as many dot products as possible match up.

Note: I know, this is definitely not a prove but I am just sharing my intuition for the problem. I would be gladful for some comments on that.

Comment: In what is written above the line, what is the point of introducing $b$ and the assumption on the system of linear equations? You don't refer to it in your goal and the assumption that there exists such a $b$ doesn't put any restrictions on $A$.

Comment: I totally get your point and I was actually thinking about whether I should include this potentially useless information. 
On the the other hand, the existence of a solution does actually yield some additional structure to the problem - which might help some of you. (I know that on another occasion, this specific fact helped me coming up with a solution). And I tried to explain the problem in such a way, that this „clutter“ didn’t render the question incomprehensible. I hope I succeeded.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem but it took around 3 Latex pages of math, so if someone is interested, please reach out :)